# JSON Initial capital key issue with parsing in GSON

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-studio, gson

I have previously JSON response in REST API like below,

Example,

> {"id":"1234"}.

I created an POJO class to set it like below.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And I am parsing with GSON like below

```
Example response = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, Example .class);
```

Now, response is changed to

> {"Id":"1234"}

And my whole parsing is returning me null due to initial capital letter.

I tried many things to solve it out but I can't get any solution for it. I have only suggestions like

- you should change name of @SerializedName with initial capital (but I have thousands of objects)

Is there any solution that GSON won't depend upon capitalization or lower case of key?

Comment: try putting capital ID in @SerializedName("Id") instead of @SerializedName("id")

Comment: You can just globally replace all `@SerializedName("id")` with `@SerializedName("Id")`.

Comment: @Nitesh thanks for your suggestion but I need alternative to do such change. because I have thousands of object with SerializedName ..

Comment: @mixel don't you think, that answer which you marked duplicate is of 2011. and this question is asked on 2015 year. 4 years of gap make simply a good library changes.

Comment: did you try using the `FieldNamingPolicy` ?

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi nope.. how can i do that..

Comment: can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096274/serialization-object-to-json-using-gson-how-to-set-field-names-in-camelcase

Comment: @ChintanRathod Not much changed since 2011 https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-roadmap

Comment: you can use `UPPER_CAMEL_CASE` that is what you need

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [FieldNamingPolicy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html) in your Gson Builder like this :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                .create();
```

I think in your case you will need to use LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES or LOWER_CASE_WITH_DASHES based which separator you want to use.

[From the docs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html) if you set this flag it will convert camel cased form to a lower case field name.

EDIT:
The SerializedName annotation will override any field naming policy so you need to be careful with it -> [source](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

Comment: I think that `UPPER_CAMEL_CASE` is better suited for his needs.

Comment: Nope.. After implementing your solution, it can't solve my problem with UPPER_CAMEL_CASE.

Comment: That's why I recommended you to use LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES or LOWER_CASE_WITH_DASHES  because you want to change "Id" to "id" right?