# Traverse an arraylist of objects and get the maximum quantity value from duplicate objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections

So I have this ArrayList of Product objects. What I'm doing is on click of + button, I am making an object of Product and setting all the attributes from ui; including 'quantity' and adding this object to ArrayList. Now, as I'm adding a single object on single click of + button, I'm getting duplicate Product objects with all same attributes other than, of course, 'quantity' count. If I add a product with quantity of 4, I get 4 objects of Product inside arraylist with different quantity 1,2,3 and 4. I only want to have Product object with maximum quantity inside the collection. I have used Comparator for this problem, but I am doing something wrong here. Please help find out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks. Here's the model of Product with getter and setters excluded from snippet.

Product:

```
private String category;
private String code;
private String description;
private String units;
private String weight;
private Integer tax;
private String pieces;
private Integer aliasFlag;
private Double price;
private Integer quantity;
private Integer taxAmount;
private Double totalAmount;
```

What I'm doing so far to compare two or more(as per the quantity count) objects of Product using Comparator is:

```
Collections.sort(mProductsToBeSent, new Comparator<Products>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Products ob1, Products ob2) {
                    if (ob1.getCode().equals(ob2.getCode())) {
                        if (ob1.getQuantity()<ob2.getQuantity()){
                            mProductsToBeSent.remove(ob1);
                        }
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            });
```

mProductToBeSent is my ArrayList that I'm gonna have to send as a Json, but since there is duplication, this won't do. I'm comparing 'Code' attribute of two subsequent objects for the same product and if it's true then I'm comparing the 'Quantity'. If it's true then I'm removing the lesser quantity object from the list. But I'm not getting desired output.

The output I'm getting right now:

> [
>   Products{Aliasflag='0', Code ='BMA10K', Description=abc, Price=270.0, Quantity=1, Taxamount=0, Units='BAGS'},
>   Products{Aliasflag='0', Code ='BMA10K', Description=def, Price=270.0, Quantity=2, Taxamount=0, Units='BAGS'},
>  
>   Products{Aliasflag='0', Code ='BMA10K', Description=ghi, Price=270.0, Quantity=3, Taxamount=0, Units='BAGS'},
>  
>   Products{Aliasflag='0', Code ='BMA10K', Description=jkl, Price=270.0, **Quantity=4**, Taxamount=0, Units='BAGS'}
> ]

As you can see, I'm trying to remove the first three objects to be deleted and only preserve the object with max quantity in the arraylist; that is 4th object--in this case.

Desired output :

> [
>   Products{Aliasflag='0', Code ='BMA10K', Description=jkl, Price=270.0, **Quantity=4**, Taxamount=0, Units='BAGS'}
> ]

Comment: A comparator is supposed to compare. It's supposed to return a positive integer, 0, or a negative integer depending on which of the two compared objects is the largest. It's not supposed to remove anythign from any collection, and it's not supposed to always return 0. Don't use sort() to do something other than sorting. Don't use a comparator to do something other than comparing. And respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: If you want help, you should describe what you want to do, precisely, with example inputs and outputs.

Comment: You are right about sorting. I am aware of Java naming conventions. It's just I'm using Gson library to convert my Java obejcts to Json representation and sending it to api. In my Json representation, the backend team is sending me the data with these keys, so I'm forced to make my model as per the same variable names. It's even awkward for me to name them as such. Thanks for the reply, I'll look for another possible solution.

Comment: I read your question a few times and I still don't understand what you want. Do you want to remove duplicates or what?

Comment: Yeah, I want to remove duplicates. I've clearly mentioned " I only want to have Product object with maximum quantity inside the collection". Sorry.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added what you've suggested in the question.

Comment: Breaking the conventions is not the right way to solve your Gson problem. The first google result for (Gson customize property names" is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096274/object-serialization-to-json-using-gson-how-to-set-field-names-in-uppercamelc. And of course, there's also the documentation. Why does nobody read documentation?

Comment: @JBNizet Alright! Thanks for the info. I have now implemented field naming policy in every model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is not to add a different product into your list with just another quantity value, but to get the product out of the list and update its quantity.

Wrote as answer because I cannot just comment and I think it will help you.

Comment: Hi, as per your suggestion, I did some changes to flow and I'm getting desired output. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
mProductsToBeSent.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getCode,
               Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Category::getQuantity))));
```

You will obtain a map `Map<String, Optional<Product>>`, now can convert it to a `List` in this way :

```
yourObtainedMap.entrySet()
     .stream().map(entry -> entry.getValue().get())
     .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: what about `if (ob1.getCode().equals(ob2.getCode())` this logic in the question?

Comment: @nullpointer - oh yeah, didn't notice. Then you just group them by ``Code``. I updated it, thanks.

Comment: @mondoteck, Thanks for your solution, unfortunately, I can't use Streaming in my android app as there's restriction about using Java 8 functionalities; some of them. But I've found some third party libraries and try to rectify this. I'm sorry for not mentioning 'Android' tag.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes - the Java 8 functionality have been introduced in Android for quite a long time now. You just have to enable the ``jackOptions``, search on google how you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove elements from a list while you're sorting it.

I would do this as a comparator:

```
new Comparator<Products>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Products ob1, Products ob2) {
                    if (ob1.getCode().equals(ob2.getCode())) {
                        if (ob1.getQuantity()<ob2.getQuantity()){
                            return -1;
                        } else if (ob1.getQuantity()<ob2.getQuantity()){
                            return 1;
                        } else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            }
```

You can then remove the duplicates:

```
String prevCode = "";
for (int i = mProductsToBeSent.size(); --i >= 0) {
    Products prod = mProductsToBeSent.get(i);
    if (prod.getCode().equals(prevCode)) {
        mProductsToBeSent.remove(i);
    } else {
        prevCode = prod.getCode();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

But if you keep your list sorted by product code, you can remove duplicates whenever you're adding to the quantity:

```
private static final Comparator<Products> PRODUCTS_CODE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Products>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Products ob1, Products ob2) {
                        return ob1.getCode().compareTo(ob2.getCode());
                    }
                };
```

To add a Products object:

```
int pos = Collections.binarySearch(mProductsToBeSent, obj, PRODUCTS_CODE_COMPARATOR);

if (pos >= 0) {
    // already in the list
    Products obj2 = mProductsToBeSent.get(pos);
    obj2.setQuantity(obj2.getQuantity() + obj.getQuantity());
} else {
    // not found: insert obj
    mProductsToBeSent.add(-pos-1, obj);
}
```

Comment: *You can't remove elements from a list while you're sorting it.* please explain why.

Comment: @nullpointer well, I have not written the sorting methods of the JVM, but if I was writing one, I certainly wouldn't want the comparator to have the side effect of removing elements from the list I am sorting.