# is it possible to Change the json name of fields of a class by annotating the object of the class instead of annotating the fields

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

```
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

This object contains a pair . When it is converted to json it's value is displayed as :

> _first : 1.0 ,
>   _second : 2.0

i want to change the name of the variable first and second to some string.

Can I change the name of the fields using annotation on the object 
for example

```
    class one {

    @SerializedName("number")
    int num ;

    @Some annotation to change the name of field one and field two
    Pair<Double,Double> var;

    Pair<String,Integer> var2;
    }

    class Pair<T1,T2>{

    T1 field_1;
    T2 field_2;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the class whose instance is obj?

Comment: class Example{ int num ; pair<double,double> marks }

Comment: Okay, that's a class. What is `obj`?

Comment: I have passed the object of this class

Comment: Please show your pair class

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096274/object-serialization-to-json-using-gson-how-to-set-field-names-in-uppercamelc

Comment: @cricket_007 I dont want to change the name of the pair . I want to change the name of the variables inside it

Comment: @cricket_007 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pair-class-in-java/

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: I want to change the name of elements of a pair . BY deafult it is _first and _ second @LHCHIN

Comment: @HeenaMittal, there is no annotation which could do this by default. You need to write custom serialiser for a whole `One` class and provide custom names for `Pair` inside fields. Probably the easiest solution right now would be to use `Map<String, Object>` and provide keys and values you need.

Comment: You should be getting `field_1` and `field_2`, by default, not _first and _second. But you must annotate the fields of the Pair class, not the Pair class itself, as that would rename the `var` or `var2` keys of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a custom Serializer for solving this problem:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Pair.class, new PairCustomSerializer());

public class PairCustomSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Pair<?, ?>> {

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Pair<?, ?> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            JsonArray arr = new JsonArray();
            if (src.getFirst() instanceof Double) {
                Double val1 = (Double) src.getFirst();
                Double val2 = (Double) src.getSecond();
                arr.add(val1);
                arr.add(val2);
                obj.add("value", arr);
                return obj;
}
```