# How to Replace SerializedName

Tags: java, gson

Assuming the JSON i want is `{"grrrr":"zzzzz"}`

```
class MyClass{
    @SerializedName("grrrr")
    private String myString;
}
```

The above class is fine.

However:

```
class MyClass{
    @MyAnnotation("grrrr")
    private String myString;
}
```

This would produce `{"myString":"zzzzz"}`

How to make Gson recognise `MyAnnotation#value()` and process as `SerializedName#value()`?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096274/object-serialization-to-json-using-gson-how-to-set-field-names-in-uppercamelc

Comment: That is not exactly what I need. I have updated the question, please take another look at it, thank you.

Comment: What's the use case? I mean, why can't you just use `@SerializedName` directly?

Comment: To make Gson recognize a home-made annotation, implement a custom `FieldNamingStrategy`

Answer (score 2):

To make Gson recognize a home-made annotation, implement a custom `FieldNamingStrategy`.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@interface MyAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

```
class MyNamingStrategy implements FieldNamingStrategy {
    @Override
    public String translateName(Field f) {
        MyAnnotation annotation = f.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        if (annotation != null)
            return annotation.value();
        // Use a built-in policy when annotation is missing, e.g.
        return FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY.translateName(f);
    }
}
```

You then specify it when creating the `Gson` object.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingStrategy(new MyNamingStrategy())
        .create();
```

And use it like in the question.

```
class MyClass{
    @MyAnnotation("grrrr")
    private String myString;
}
```

Note that `@SerializedName` overrides any defined strategy, so if you specify both `@SerializedName` and `@MyAnnotation`, the `@SerializedName` value will be used.